# Why is Blazor using post instead of WebSockets?

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app.  When I run the app in Visual Studio, I see this message in the Browser console:

```
 WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:44329/_blazor?id=HX5t9UdbZwj35PkMxV3Fkw.
```

So it looks to me like SignalR is working as expected.  On the Network Tab, I see signalR working as expected with message:

However, now I publish the App to IIS.  The app works fine.  However, if I look in the browser console, I no longer see WebSocket being connected. What I see in the network tab looks like this:

```
Request URL: https://blazor/_blazor?id=O_acVtnuEIOjlRAosu1YFg
Request Method: POST
```

There are many many of these like 1 per second.

So it looks like SignalR is no longer being used.

Why is this?  What do I need to do to ensure SignalR is being used?

Comment: Have you installed/enabled websocket support on IIS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support

Comment: I had not, and I have now updated the server to use WebSockets. If you want to post as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure WebSockets has been enabled on IIS. Here is a brief overview:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support